# Syntax Error while executing Stored Procedure in Snowflake

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

if I execute the CREATE table statement seperately it executes fine ,but if I put that in Stored Procedure then I get the below error.
[image]

Comment: can you try without using the WHERE clause and see if you are getting an error.

Comment: @hkandpal - requirement is i should filter the data only for certain apply_dt. Code executes fine outside of the Stored Procedure. I have even tried giving double quotes for "yyyy-mm"  with in stored procedure and that didnt work either. Thanks for your time on this

Comment: I think it might be that the SUM() in your SELECT needs a column name.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @MikeWalton - yes I updated that and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following select statement in the procedure and see if it works fine :

```
    (select apply_dt from Date_details as <alias name>)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response